# Calling a password checking command from PHP using exec() - how to escape user input?

Tags: php, c, pam, escape-characters

I am working on a PHP-based website where the login form needs to authenticate against local users on the system via PAM - in other words, they should be able to login successfully if they enter a valid username and password for a local user account on the server. The website originally accomplished this using the [php-auth-pam](https://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) module, but since it has been deprecated, I am currently having to look around for an alternative solution.

I eventually came across [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105098/securest-way-to-authenticate-users-against-etc-shadow-using-php) with a helpful C script for authenticating against PAM. I successfully compiled it into an executable named `chkpasswd`, and to check a username/password combo I simply run:

`./chkpasswd username password`

It outputs "Authenticated" if the credentials are valid, and "Not authenticated" if they are not. That part works like a charm, no problems there.

But pretty soon I realized there was a glaring issue - this setup doesn't work properly when passwords contain special characters! It will say the user is not authenticated even when the credentials are correct. I am calling `chkpasswd` using PHP's `exec()` function, and using `escapeshellarg()` to escape the user input. Here's the PHP code:

```
function pam_auth2($username, $password){
    $result = exec("/usr/local/sbin/chkpasswd ".escapeshellarg($username)." ".escapeshellarg($password));

    if ($result == "Authenticated"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

So here are my main questions:

1. Is it possible to modify either the C script or the PHP code that calls it so that the system properly handles passwords with special characters?
2. How secure is this setup overall? Are there any glaring vulnerabilities I should know about?

Comment: The usernames and passwords dangling out in the open in the process table for `ps(1)` and such to read is one minor issue with this plan.

Comment: Have you looked at mod_authnz_external and something like pwauth (https://code.google.com/p/pwauth/wiki/InstallApache), which talks over a pipe rather than as a command argument?

Comment: @jsbillings omg pwauth is perfect, thank you! Can't believe I didn't find that before.