# How to authenticate Linux accounts with PAM using PHP without giving www-data shadow

Tags: php, authentication, pam, ubuntu

Sort of as a follow up to this: [Securest way to authenticate users against /etc/shadow using PHP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105098/securest-way-to-authenticate-users-against-etc-shadow-using-php) and because there hasn't been anything relevant that I've seen on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to authenticate Linux accounts (Ubuntu 16.04) via HTTP with `PECL-PAM` but the issue that I run into is that `www-data` has to be in `shadow` group in order to authenticate against `/etc/shadow`. The work around that I found was to use `mod_authnz_external` and `pwauth` but the issue with that combination is that past authentication there is no identity to the user logged in that I've been able to find so far.

My end goal is to have users authenticate via HTTP/PHP and then be able to manage files from their home directory (that is, `/somedir/$user`). I was originally using Webmin but encountered some other issues with the usermin `filemin` module so switched to a more home made solution.

Is it possible to use the PHP/PAM package to authenticate without www-data being in the shadow group? Or if that's not possible, is it possible to use the `mod_authnz_external` and `pwauth` and start a session with the user who logged in?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_authnz_external` sets the variable `PHP_AUTH_USER` when a user has been successfully authenticated.

You can start a session like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    // Your code which uses the username set in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`
    // to set up a session.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler/safer to use an existing service running on the box to handle the access to the tokens / validation?  (ssh2_auth_password(), imap_open() .... )